# Recursion in C: "return --Z % 9 + 1" what is going on?

Tags: c, math, integer-arithmetic

I was doing a challenge to sum up digits from an int and return it only when it's less than 10.

For example:

```
12 should return 1 + 2 = 3.
123 should return 1 + 2 + 3 = 6.
but 99 should return 9, cause 9 + 9 = 18 and 1 + 8 = 9.
```

so the result must always be less than 10.

Seeing others solutions after completing someone has done this:

```
int digital_root(int Z) {
  return --Z % 9 + 1;
}
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

I came up with this solution:

```
int digital_root(int n) {
  int time = n;
  int i = 0;
  int base = time;
  while(base > 0)
  {
    i++;
    base = base / 10;
  }

  int num = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {

    num = num + (time % 10);
    time = time / 10;
  }
  if(num > 9) {
    num = digital_root(num);
  }

  return num; 
}
```

Comparing my code to others as well everyone had done something similar to what I did. Sadly the dude who posted this didn't explain it.

Comment: it's more an arithmetic question. Summed up in the accepted answer of the linked Q&A: "Taking the modulo 9 of any number will return the sum of digits of that number until a single digit number is obtained"

Comment: note the approach needs more though for negative input. `--Z % 9 + 1` is a particularly flashy way.

Comment: @Bathsheba I suggest that you answer in the original link if you understood what's going on fully and if it improves over the accepted answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Methinks it's borderline off topic for what's essentially a programming site. The dupe you link ought to set the OP off on their way.

Comment: that plus any comments you want to help, I think that's cool already :) thanks for feedback

Comment: @Bathsheba that part was what I didn't understand why the --Z and then + 1! Thanks! So you think programming doesn't relate to math?

Comment: @EmersonLopes: Yeah, it saves a branch so obviating the possibility of a pipeline dump.

Comment: wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root